# How can I send traffic between two Virtual Machines which are created on two different virtual networks in azure cloud

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-virtual-network

I created two virtual networks in azure using the routeable private adress configurations

vnet1: 172.16.10.0/24(vsubnet1)
vnet2: 172.16.20.0/24(vsubnet2)

I Created two virtual machines by connecting to the above vsubnets through NIC.

Network security Group has been defined to allow all the traffic and no additional routes are created.
How can I approach this connectivity between these two virtual machines without creating VPN/Express route as given in Azure [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/vnet-to-vnet-connecting-virtual-networks-in-azure-across-different-regions/)

In Openstack we have the option of creating the interfaces that connect to ports of multiple virtual networks where as in azure, the NIC configuration is limited only to one virtual network which vm connects to.

Comment: this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Virtual neteork peering. IT enables you to seamlessly connect two Azure virtual networks. Once peered, the virtual networks appear as one, for connectivity purposes. The traffic between virtual machines in the peered virtual networks is routed through the Microsoft backbone infrastructure, much like traffic is routed between virtual machines in the same virtual network, through private IP addresses only.

For more information refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vnet peering to connect two vnets.

For now, Peering virtual networks in the **same region** is generally available. Peering virtual networks in **different regions is currently in preview** in `US West Central, Canada Central, US West 2, Korea South, UK South, UK West, Canada East, India South, India Central, and India West`.

Please make sure your virtual networks must have non-overlapping IP address spaces.

Vnet peering works like this:

[image]

More information about requirements of vnet peering, please refer to this [article](http://Peering%20virtual%20networks%20in%20the%20same%20region%20is%20generally%20available.%20Peering%20virtual%20networks%20in%20different%20regions%20is%20currently%20in%20preview%20in%20US%20West%20Central,%20Canada%20Central,%20US%20West%202,%20Korea%20South,%20UK%20South,%20UK%20West,%20Canada%20East,%20India%20South,%20India%20Central,%20and%20India%20West.).

Here is the official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-connect-virtual-networks-portal) about enable vnet peering via Azure portal, please refer to it.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more help:)